# How do I just the Jest runner with the watch option

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular16

I'm testing the new experimental jest runner that shipped with v16. (`@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest`).

Do have any idea how to run with the `--watch` option ?

Maybe it's not ready yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) repo which provides the runners:

As of today, it's [not present in the settings](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/57f0be7990288b611ee68603ce45a1a8b024e6bb/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/jest/schema.json).

We'll see it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/jest/schema.json) when it's available.

Comment: Same problem for me, took me a while to understand its not exists yet. also unable to debug tests without configure jest in the "old way"